# JSON support in Jersey 2.0-m2

Tags: json, maven, jersey, jackson, grizzly

(my first post to Stackoverflow, new to maven and Jersey  ;-)

trying to develop a standalone jersey-JSON-application, I started with the latest mvn archetype

```
    mvn archetype:generate org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-grizzly2
```

This is by default without JSON-Support. I managed to import and run this in Eclipse and see the "got it!" page in my Browser. JSON-Support can (?) be activated by uncommenting lines in pom.xml and in Main.java. So, in a new project generated with maven, I activated following dependency in pom.xml:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

... then imported to Eclipse with mvn eclipse:eclipse. Then in Eclipse, edit Main.java and uncomment following line:

```
    rc.addBinder(org.glassfish.jersey.media.json.JsonJaxbBinder);
```

Which leads to the following compilation error: "org.glassfish.jersey.media cannot be resolved to a variable".

And then I'm stuck. Where did I go wrong ?

Also I'd like to understand what "JSON support" means ? In an earlier version of my program based on jersey-1.17, I managed to use @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}) Annotations on my Rest-resource. In the "Referenced Libraries" I see four jackson-libraries. In the new project I dont see any jackson-libraries. Is that because the dependencies were not resolved correctly ? Or is jersey-2.0 no longer using Jackson ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: could you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

The comment in the Main class seems to be totally misleading, since:

- jersey-media-moxy doesn't include org.glassfish.jersey.media.json.JsonJaxbBinder class
- ResourceConfig doesn't have addBinder method (at least in current 2.0-rc1 version)

Anyway, you can still use Jackson with Jersey 2.0. Just include a dependency to jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and register the JacksonJaxbJsonProvider:

```
rc.register(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
```